# looking for C w/openssl equivalent of java bouncycastle SHA256withRSA signing

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, bouncycastle

ok ive been banging my head on this for over two days now. I need to code in c, using openssl library, the equivalent for the following java code :

```
    byte[] result = null;
    Signature st = Signature.getInstance(BC_PROV_ALGORITHM_SHA256RSA, "BC");
    st.initSign(privateKey);
    st.update(data);
    result = st.sign();
    return result;
```

The most obvious approach was this

```
RSA_sign( NID_sha256, ( const BYTE* ) pszMessage256Hash, 
strlen( pszMessage256Hash), ( unsigned char *) pSignature, 
&iSignLen, pPrivateMerchantKey )
```

Already checked that the key is the same and the content of the pszMessage256Hash is identical to the "data" variable from java. Due to padding the result is different every time however the server-side verification is rejecting the second signature.

Any help would be appreciated, as i said, i have been wasting way too much time on this.

Comment: Um... `pszMessage256Hash` ? If that lives up to its name, It may already be wrong on *multiple* fronts. First, `RSA_sign` will digest the data, then produce the signature via encryption with the given key. If that name is accurate, you *already* have the digest. So you're digesting a digest, then signing that (and obviously that can't work). Second, if that is some *string* of the digest (and the `strlen` suggests that *may* be the case), then you're digesting a character hex-dump of a digest, then signing it (which is arguably just as inaccurate, but just obfuscating things more).

Comment: yes pszMessage256Hash contains a string with 64 lowercase hex characters which is the representation of the sha256 32 bytes( 256bit ) hash. Same as data[] in the java module.

Comment: So you're *intentionally* digesting a hex-char-encoded digest (from... somewhere), then signing the result? Just want to be clear. And `data` in the java code is a *string* ? Or is it `byte[]`

Comment: That is correct. The java code is a byte[] containing 64 hex characters but could very well be a string. The content of both data[] and pszMessage256Hash is a hash of the actual message and was very straightforward to obtain and verify using online tools. The SHA256WithRSA signature for that content however only checks out if it is generated by the java code snippet - the one generated by the c code is rejected.

Comment: OK. I hope you understand my asking. signatures are normally built from digests of the *data*, signed with the asymmetric private key. Your *data* is already a digest, making your ultimate end result a signature of a digest of a digest. Odd, but doable; data is, after all, data. What online checking tool are you using for this? Perhaps include that [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51731802/edit). Thanks.

Comment: yeah it looks pretty weird to me too but that is what the specifications require, and what their java sample does.
To check the sha256 i have googled for "online sha256" and used some of the links provided. However that is an input parameter that is not random so i was able to check that it is the same on both versions.

Comment: Since you are doing the signing you can also do the verification as another way of checking your code. Specifically, you can write a C language verifier to check the Java signature and a Java language verifier to check the C language signature. This can possibly narrow down your problem.

Comment: An example using the EVP library in OpenSSL for generating and verifying signatures can be [seen **here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efde4dd40226204a). Note there is literally no error checking, so use at your discretion, but I just wanted you to know how a signature is typically generated, and verified, using modern (post 1.0) OpenSSL's libcrypto.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you !